# How to resolve error in react when it us unable to resolve Auth0 package?

Tags: reactjs, authentication, jsx, auth0, auth0-connection

I am using Auth0 for login functionality and it is giving this error.

[image]

Comment: `npm install @auth0/auth0-react` should do the trick. See this page for more options: https://auth0.com/docs/libraries/auth0-react

Comment: Still, it is showing the same error. I have tried to install it 2 to 4 times but the same error is happening